# Change color of button using css or tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

i am trying to change color on buttons when main button is clicked, one color is changing why the other buttons color is not changing, is it because it's outside main `<div>` how can i achieve it, without removing any div.

**[code](https://play.tailwindcss.com/hn4kwAFd0X?file=css)**

```css
button.one:focus~div.two {
  background-color: rgba(185, 28, 28, 1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div>

<button class="one   bg-red-400 font-bold px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">MAIN BUTTON</button>

<div class="two bg-blue-400 font-bold  px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">RED
</div>

</div>

<div class="two bg-blue-400 font-bold  px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">MAKE THIS RED TOO</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

In Chrome, the `button` was *taking* the click, and the parent `div` was not receiving the focus. I made a few adjustments to this and it is now working properly in Chrome.

1. Ignore direct clicks to the `button` via `pointer-events: none`.
2. To keep things somewhat accessible, I added:

   - `aria-hidden="true"` to the `button`, so that screen readers won't read it aloud to users.
   - `aria-label="MAIN BUTTON"` and `role="button" to the parent` div`, so that screen readers can treat the` div` like a button.
   - `cursor: pointer` to the parent `div`, so that it feels like a button (from a UX perspective).

---

The only pure `CSS` way to do this is to add `tabindex="0"` to the outer `div`, which lets us use its focus and general sibling combinator (`~`) to our advantage. I gave the `div` an <s>`inline`</s> `inline-block` display, so that the clickable region was the exact width of its child content.

```css
div[tabindex="0"] {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

div:focus .two,
div:focus~.two {
  background-color: rgba(185, 28, 28, 1);
}

div[tabindex="0"] > button {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="MAIN BUTTON">

  <button aria-hidden="true" class="one bg-red-400 font-bold px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">MAIN BUTTON</button>

  <div class="two bg-blue-400 font-bold  px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">RED
  </div>

</div>

<div class="two bg-blue-400 font-bold  px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">MAKE THIS RED TOO</div>
```

Comment: when i click on main button/first button nothing is changing?

Comment: @Fayakon I updated my answer for you. Sorry for the issue.

Comment: Thankyou, can you please tell/fix why it's not working if i add one div above tab index; https://play.tailwindcss.com/PnAJCarYYz

Comment: @Fayakon Your `HTML` is different there than what you included in your question. Also, your `CSS` was working at all at the tailwind sandbox. Have a look at this: https://play.tailwindcss.com/H61nnozDBn

Comment: it's working, but when i add one extra div above tab index why it stops working?https://play.tailwindcss.com/PnAJCarYYz

Comment: @Fayakon The general sibling combinator (`~`) can only find sibling elements. As of today, `CSS` can't travel up in the DOM to parent elements.